# Team Foundation Server: How to get project's latest build number from command line?

Tags: command-line, tfs

I want to use to tf.exe command line utility and I want it to output the latest build revision number. (So output would be: '159' for example)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well TFS sux :> and I have the same problem. One solution that I came up with this:

```
tf properties . | grep "Server information" -A 3  | grep Changeset | gawk 'BEGIN {FS = ":"};{ sub(/^[ \t]+/, "",$2); print $2}'
```

to get the latest changeset number:

```
tf changeset /latest /noprompt | grep Changeset | gawk 'BEGIN {FS = ":"};{ sub(/^[ \t]+/, "",$2); print $2}'
```

grep and gawk are available at: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/
this gets the version of the file/folder specified after properties.